# Unity - Deprecated EditorApplication

Tags: unity-game-engine

I just have updated my Unity to 5.3.1 and it seems like `EditorApplication` class is already deprecated. The Unity suggests me to use instead the `EditorSceneManager.OpenScene` but looks like it's not returning of type `bool` anymore. Therefore causing my game to stop compiling.

Any help about this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Usually due to deprecated code unity itself offers some changes in your code you can make a backup and try that if unity informs you of it ,but if you want to know if it has been loaded or not you can use its return value which is a struct of type Scene.

```
SceneManagement.Scene newScene = EditorSceneManager.OpenScene("myScene");
if(newScene.isLoaded) { 
      //do something 
}
```

There is another method also named IsVaild You Can try that too.
further doc :
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.Scene.html

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to help you without any information on what you actually want to do... [This link](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UpgradeGuide53.html) may help though, it's about upgrading to Unity 5.3.

Comment: Sorry for lack of details. To be exact, `EditorApplication.OpenScene` returns a `bool`. Now that it was deprecated, it was suggesting me to use `EditorSceneManager.OpenScene` but doesn't return `bool` anymore.